# react-native firebase fetch() operation cannot be completed successfully ,due to throttling

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
remoteKey = "testJSON"
 firebase
            .config()
            .fetch(0)
            .then(() => {
                return firebase.config().activateFetched();
            })
            .then(activated => {
                if (!activated) console.log("Fetched data not activated");
                return firebase.config().getKeysByPrefix(remoteKey);
            });
```

I am calling this inside App.js in my react native project, but it gives the error "fetch() operation cannot be completed ,due to throttling"
What could be the issue ?

Comment: Have you tried searching on internet for the solution? What you have tried?

Answer (score 4):

According to firebase documentation it means that config fetch was throttled
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Enums/FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatus?hl=vi

```
The Remote Config library has a client-side throttle to ensure you don’t ping the service too frequently. By setting your fetchDuration to 0, you’ll hit this throttle and your library will stop making calls.
```

Try changing .fetch(0) to .fetch() or use the following function to activate development mode

```
func activateDebugMode() {
    let debugSettings = FIRRemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
    FIRRemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configSettings = debugSettings!
}
```

and call it before.

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
remoteKey = "testJSON";
firebase
  .config()
  .fetch()
  .then(() => {
    return firebase.config().activateFetched();
  })
  .then(activated => {
    if (!activated) console.log("Fetched data not activated");
    return firebase.config().getKeysByPrefix(remoteKey);
  });
```